# Check whether a Cstring contains only Chinese characters

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, operators

I am checking whether a CString variable contains only] Chinese characters. The Unicode range for Chinese characters is 4E00 - 9FFF.

I am doing as follows:

```
CString str;
char ch;
GetDlgItemText( IDC_EDIT1, str );

for(int i=0;i<str.GetLength();i++) {
  ch=str[i];
  if(ch>='\u4E00'&&ch<='\u9FFF') {
  //even if input chinese character here 'if' evaluates to false
    SetDlgItemText( IDC_RICHEDIT21, str );
    SendDlgItemMessage( IDC_RICHEDIT21, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)str);
  } else
    break;
```

But if I do

```
if(ch=='\u4E00')
```

and input the symbol of \u4E00 then it works fine.

So my question is, how to find weather a character lies between a particular Unicode range?

One more thing: if I use `if(ch=='\u4e00')` then it gives true, but if I do `if(ch<='\u4e00')` it returns false. I don't understand this behavior!

My code is

```
CString str;
wchar_t ch;
GetDlgItemText( IDC_EDIT1, str );
for(int i=0;i<str.GetLength();i++) {
  ch=str[i];
  if(ch<='\u4e01') {
    //returns false,  but returns true if(ch=='\u4e01')
    SetDlgItemText( IDC_RICHEDIT21, str );
    SendDlgItemMessage( IDC_RICHEDIT21, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)str);
  else
    break;
}
```

Comment: Um, you are using char, not wchar.

Comment: if i use wchar i am getting error as follows,   test3Dlg.cpp(155): error C2065: 'wchar' : undeclared identifier

Comment: It's `WCHAR` (defined by the Windows headers), or `wchar_t` to use the C++ type.

Comment: That is the range for CJK Unified Ideographs. Don't forget about the CJK Radicals Supplement, Kangxi Radicals, CJK Symbols and Punctuation, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A, CJK Compatibility Ideographs, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D, or CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement. Note that some of these are above U+FFFF. And don't forget about the upcoming CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E or F, which do not yet have codepoints. Likely you'll need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are ignoring warnings from the compiler.  Don't.  Casting just digs you a deeper hole.  A wide character literal requires a L in front, like `L'\u4e00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It can be compared as follows:

```
CString str;
wchar_t ch;
GetDlgItemText( IDC_EDIT1, str );

for(int i=0;i<str.GetLength();i++) {
  ch=str[i];
  if((unsigned int)ch>=0x4E00u&&(unsigned int)ch<=ox9FFFu) {
    SetDlgItemText( IDC_RICHEDIT21, str);
    SendDlgItemMessage( IDC_RICHEDIT21, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)str);
  } else
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Chinese character ranges:

- U+3400 - U+4DB5
- U+4E00 - U+62FF
- U+6300 - U+77FF
- U+7800 - U+8CFF
- U+8D00 - U+9FCC
- U+20000 - U+215FF
- U+21600 - U+230FF
- U+23100 - U+245FF
- U+24600 - U+260FF
- U+26100 - U+275FF
- U+27600 - U+290FF
- U+29100 - U+2A6DF
- U+2A700 - U+2B734
- U+2B740 - U+2B81D

You'll have to check all these ranges to be complete and thorough.

Comment: Which means you have to update the code to take UTF-16 surrogates into account in order to handle Chinese codepoints U+20000 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

The range of "char" type is -128~127 or 0~255 depending on your compiler.
You should use "wchar_t" or "unsigned short" to make it range from 0 to 65535 or the varible cannot represent that unicode chars.

Btw, you should not place SetDlgItemText and SendDlgItemMessage in that "if" block. define variable "i" before "for" and check if the value of i equals str.Length() after loop.

Comment: i replaced char with wchar_t but still the problem persists!

Comment: You also need to ensure that the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols are defined globally for your project, or explicitly use `CStringW` and `GetDlgItemTextW` (and the `W` suffixed versions of all the SDK functions). @nomesh

Comment: if i use if(ch=='\u4e00') then it gives true , but if i do if(ch<='\u4e00')  it returns false.. i am not undersanding this behaviour!   please help me

Comment: @NomeshGajare is there any warnings about this piece of code during compiling? you may also try: 1. use CStringW instead of CString. 2. use GetDlgItemTextW instead of GetDlgItemText. 3. use SetDlgItemText instead of SetDlgItemText. 4. use SendDlgItemMessageW instead of SendDlgItemMessage.